# Find all indices of a value in a dictionary python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary created from variables in a netCDF file.  I have also sorted all of these variables in the order of time. There are repeated values for some of the keys.  I want to find all of the indices for a specific value in one key and retrieve the corresponding indices from another key:

For example:

```
test_dict = {}
test_dict['time'] = [1,2,3,4]
test_dict['number'] = [12,14,12,13]
test_dict['number2'] = [20,21,22,23]
```

in test_dict I want to find the indices of all occurrences of 12 in the key 'number' and get the corresponding values in 'number2'. So the result should be:

```
idx = [0,2]
nums_interest = [test_dict['number2'][i] for i in idx]
>>>> [20,22]
```

I have tried to find the number of unique values in 'number' using:

```
num_unique = np.unique(test_dict['number'])
>>>> [12,13,14]
```

Then I want to find all indices of these unique occurrences.

```
 idx2 = [test_dict['number'].index(num_unique[0])
 >>> 0
```

I have two main problems: 1.  I can find the first index, but not repeating indices. 
2. I want to loop through the list of unique numbers and get indices for every unique value not just num_unique[0]
question: what is the best way to find indices for a certain value in a dictionary and extract the values for the same indices in a different key?

Comment: Couldn't you just use `[j for i,j in zip(test_dict['number'],test_dict['number2']) if i==12]`? You don't have to find the indices of `12` that way

Comment: @GughanRavikumar That worked!

Comment: Glad to help. I've added it as an answer. If you found it useful, mark it accepted so that others reading this question can benefit from it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To return values from one key based on index of another key in a dict**

```
test_dict = {}
test_dict['number'] = [12,14,12,13]
test_dict['number2'] = [20,21,22,23]
print([j for i,j in zip(test_dict['number'],test_dict['number2']) if i==12])
```

returns `[20,22]`

**To get indices of all occurences of a value in a list**

```
indices = [i for i,j in enumerate(dict['number']) if j==12]
```

gives `indices` equals `[0,2]`